# Error 1046 Mariadb: No database selected

Tags: mariadb

```
GRANT ALL ON my-database.* TO my-user@10.0.0.1 IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
```

Ok, I have created a database with a "-" on the name (did the same thing on the user)... then when I try to set the grants on it the database wont work.

If I use the base the error is different

```
MariaDB [(none)]> use my-base
Database changed
MariaDB [my-base]> GRANT ALL ON 'my-base'.* TO 'my-user'@'10.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''my-base'.* TO 'my-user'@'10.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'' at line 1
MariaDB [my-base]>
```

Comment: In regards to the second error if you set  your database, if you're not running in ANSI-quote sql_mode, `'` doesn't escape a database object. Use the back tick `\``

Comment: Slight correction to myself...ANSI_QUOTES affects the double-quotes for escaping...single-quotation never does :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try escaping it with backticks?

```
GRANT ALL ON `my-database`.* TO `my-user`@`10.0.0.1` IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Also, if you already have a user `my-user`@`10.0.0.1`, you don't need to provide the `IDENTIFIED BY...` portion of your grant statement